Need help making a form script work where the edit url is placed at the end of the google worksheet
This script does not work from the from script editor. Also, the form gave me a permissions error on saving it but I am the owner of the script and have full permissions. I went to advanced and approved the script anyway.;
function onFormSubmit(e) {
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('CRM');  // Adjust sheet name if needed
// Get the submitted form response
var formResponse = e.response;
var editUrl = formResponse.getEditResponseUrl();  // Get the edit response URL
// Find the row in the sheet to add the edit URL
var responses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
var timestamp = e.values[0];  // The first value is the timestamp
// Find the row with the matching timestamp and add the edit URL
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
sheet.getRange(lastRow, sheet.getLastColumn() + 1).setValue(editUrl);  // Insert the edit URL in the last column
}
